# windows10 (host) Chrome won't start on Linux(Ubnutu)

Tags: linux, windows, google-chrome, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using wsl not virtualbox and I installed google-chrome on ubuntu following this instructions

```
  To install the Google Chrome for Linux:

 1. Change directories into the temp folder: cd /tmp
 2. Use wget to download it: sudo wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
 3. Get the current stable version: sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
 4. Fix the package: sudo apt install --fix-broken -y
 5. Configure the package: sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
 6. To launch, enter: google-chrome
```

but each time i try to launch the app i get following errors:

```
    [0610/104507.008457:ERROR:exception_handler_server.cc(361)] getsockopt: Invalid argument (22)
    [0610/104507.009135:ERROR:socket.cc(153)] unhandled cmsg -1431655766, -1431655766
    [0610/104507.011209:ERROR:exception_handler_server.cc(361)] getsockopt: Invalid argument (22)
    [8078:8078:0610/104507.012403:ERROR:socket.cc(153)] unhandled cmsg -1431655766, -1431655766
    Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I don't if the chrome runing on my windows is some how affecting the chrome on Ubuntu from starting up

I tried re-installing,
I have tried deleting the google-chrome config rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
I have tried launching with wslview
I have tried fixing broken
I have also tried couple of other commands
I have disabled all chrome extensions, on the chrome running on my windows

Pls, what else can i do?